# Kafka-server-stop fails to do controlled shutdown in Windows

Tags: java, windows, apache-kafka

Hi,

We are running Kafka brokers on windows and are trying to achieve graceful shutdown of Brokers. As suggested, we ran kafka-server-stop.bat. It does indeed kill the Kafka broker, but it seems like an abrupt termination instead of controlled shutdown. The reason I am concluding that the shutdown is not graceful, is because there is no shutdown log.

Interestingly, instead of running kafka-server-stop, if I just press ctr+C on the Kafka broker console, it indeed does the graceful shutdown with logs like this -

```
[2017-12-04 14:53:30,176] INFO [Kafka Server 1], shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-12-04 14:53:30,176] INFO [Kafka Server 1], shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-12-04 14:53:30,176] INFO [Kafka Server 1], Starting controlled shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-12-04 14:53:30,176] INFO [Kafka Server 1], Starting controlled shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-12-04 14:53:30,207] INFO [Kafka Server 1], Controlled shutdown succeeded (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-12-04 14:53:30,207] INFO [Kafka Server 1], Controlled shutdown succeeded (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

I have these configs set up -

```
controlled.shutdown.enable=true
controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms=15000
controlled.shutdown.max.retries=5
```

Has anyone else experienced this behavior? Controlled shutdown is critical to us, since we are setting up a dynamic cluster here same physical machine might end up with different broker ids. And without the proper shutdown we are seeing a lot of issues with controller from other cluster sending requests to machine not in its cluster anymore etc.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to close the brokers gracefully using the [NSSM service tool](https://nssm.cc/). The tool sends CONTROL-C to the console and Kafka closes neatly.

This led me to another problem, Windows's restart.  Zookeeper was terminating way before Kafka that cause Kafka hanging around searching for Zookeeper to finally get killed by the shutdown procedure.  I ended up creating a C# service that handle the SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN notifications from Windows ([details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685149(v=vs.85).aspx)).  That service then calls a batch file that is doing a "net stop" (which is synchronous) of each services in the order I wish.

This way, the Kafka service is stopped cleanly (using NSSM CONTROL-C feature) and before ZooKeeper.